# How much rep do I need to protect a question?

Tags: support, protected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

I know some uber mods can protect a question? how much rep do I need to be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No amount of reputation will grant you access to that feature.  Only the actual *♦ moderators* (diamonds) can protect questions.