# how quick to be on the 'protect' trigger

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [For 15k+ users: Guidelines on Protecting Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78762/for-15k-users-guidelines-on-protecting-questions)

So, I got the 'protect' link on stackoverflow. If I read the late answers link, I'll see plenty of pointlessness attached to old questions.

One possible approach: if the questions at least some months old, and has plenty of perfectly good answers, one 'me-too' non-answer is a good enough reason to protect.

Another possible approach: one is not enough. Just flag it for mods, and leave protect for questions that are attracting some significant volume of flies.

Comment: I'm also confused how to use this ability, 'privileges' page is terribly short about it.