# Why did this question get protected?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, protected-questions

Title says it all, really. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1837012/1015495) seems to be to worst kind of shopping question, it's three years old, low views, and it doesn't seem to have any 'Historical Significance.' If there's some nuance of this question that I'm missing, I'd love to know about it. What's the reasoning here? [This meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115372/188613) says that it can be used when mods get sick of deleting non-answers, but it kinda seems to me like we'd all be better off just getting rid of this question.

Comment: As the answer states, this is protected, not locked.  It appears to have been protected by the user who just came across this old and poor question just to make it harder for new answers to be posted before this question could be closed, and possibly deleted.  (It has since been closed, and is likely to be deleted soon.)

Comment: It makes so much sense in retrospect. I was wondering wth a high-rep user was doing protecting the question...it was protected in order to more effectively **destroy** it. Well played.

Comment: Oh, and that's in response to a recently posted (and now deleted) answer that is most likely what brought the question to the attention of that high rep user.

Comment: @Servy that's how I found the question - in the late answers queue.

Comment: It was protected 6 minutes after that post.  I don't consider it a coincidence.

Comment: If nothing else, this question has brought to light [tons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188376/quality-windows-asp-net-sql-server-2005-web-hosting?rq=1) of [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491758/reccommended-web-hosting-solution-in-the-us-not-really-programming-questions-b?rq=1) that should also be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protection just means that people below 10 rep can't post answers; this isn't the same as posts which are intentionally preserved via locking. The question can still be closed/deleted via voting, which is how things *should* work most of the time. Moderations shouldn't have to step in an make a call on the worthiness of a question, the community does this.

Comment: Ah, subtlety. 'protected' != 'locked'. Thanks for some clarification.

Comment: Yup! I tend to use 'Protect' every time I come across a question that's getting lots of 'junk' answers from 1-rep users, especially when it's not a 'good' question. It's a relatively frequent thing I come across while hunting for spam answers, for example.