# Did the algorithm for Hot Network Questions change recently?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Rather recently I've noticed that a lot of the posts that make it to the Hot Network Questions list stay there for quite a bit. For example, I was on superuser.com and saw the Hot Network Questions list that had the [What is Hermione Granger's ethnicity?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105467/what-is-hermione-grangers-ethnicity) question, which I was sure I saw just only 5 or so days ago.

There were already a sizable amount of views and upvotes on the question back then, but then I noticed it's been happening for other sites as well with some questions I could've sworn had been up there for only a week before and was still in the Hot Networks questions list without much change in terms of upvotes or views.

Did something recently change?

Comment: It was the weekend, so fewer questions meant fewer new hot network questions, so old ones weren't bumped off as much.

Comment: @HDE226868 that may be the case, but surely there have been *other* hot questions in the three days prior to the weekend that would have pushed this one off.  There are regularly HNQ that are five and six days old.  Sci-fi all male dino question is five days old. The referenced Hermione question is six days old. Parenting's too many languages is four days old. Outdoors wild dogs is four days old. World building's zombie fortress is give days old. If you believe that this is a "weekend problem", then this next friday go over all the HNQ and check to see how many of them are older than two days.

Comment: Well, it's still there but with score as low as 6.329 and the [100th Hot Question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28094/how-does-one-prove-rulership-in-a-rural-illiterate-world) got score of 6.127 - so no worry, time still plays big role in the score calculation. I think nothing has changed.

Comment: related: [Make hot questions with multiple answers age away faster on smaller / subjective-ish sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224750/165773)