# Prior to the 3-day limit for HNQ, what was the longest amount of time a question stayed on HNQ?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

There is now a 3-day limit for the HNQ.  But what was the longest amount of time that a question stayed on the HNQ for prior to that limit being instituted? I'd imagine some questions having stayed on the HNQ for well over a week.

Comment: prior to [shuffling the sidebar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222993/165773) was introduced, longest documented amount was 16 days, see [Don't let questions stick to the top of the hot questions list forever](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/165773)

Comment: I found a [mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279502/impose-strict-time-limit-for-questions-on-hot-network-questions-list#comment907018_279502) of a [question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67475/offensive-bumper-sticker-on-car) that was on HNQ for 9 days after the changes were made.  I haven't found anything longer than that.

Comment: @gnat Recently I noticed a [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114033/how-can-santa-keep-his-lists-when-gdpr-is-around) that was on the HNQ for 10 days.  I remember it seeing it on June 14, somewhere around the 70th position on HNQ.  I forgot to check it after that to see how much longer it stayed on HNQ - maybe it lasted to 11 days?

Comment: good catch, it was in HNQ since day one on June 4 and if memory serves I saw it in the list yesterday, meaning it stuck in the list for 13-14 days

Comment: @gnat I disagree that this is a duplicate given that in the [linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279502/impose-strict-time-limit-for-questions-on-hot-network-questions-list), the answer does not answer my question, nor does the highest HNQ time for any of the questions mentioned in the question/comments (9 days) exceed the highest HNQ time for any of the questions mentioned here (13-14 days).

Comment: well, I gave it a consideration prior to suggesting duplicate and after weighting pros and cons decided that for question visitors it would be less confusing this way, so that they could clearly see that examples in this list are only historical things and that actual time limit they can observe on current questions is firm and simple 3 days

Comment: @gnat So if I prepended the following to my question "Prior to questions being limited to 3 days on HNQ...", then it should no longer be a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

The limit on a question's lifetime in the HNQ has always been [limited to 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/295232) and this limit has recently been decreased to [3 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/295232). So current records are impossible to break in the future, unless the policy changes again.

I've been scraping the HNQ multiple times per day since [August 4th, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/295232). While this is only a short period in the history of HNQ, these are the questions with the longest appearance in this period:

- [Why are people developing and publishing games online without charging money?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/166313/72119) (Game Development)
  (14 days, from 2018-12-19 15:21 to 2019-01-02 16:03)
- [Search for military installed backdoors on laptop](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/199971/71850) (Information Security)
  (13 days, 14 hours, from 2018-12-18 13:03 to 2019-01-01 03:45)
- [Criticized for doing my job too well](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/124711/33983) (The Workplace)
  (13 days, 1 hour, from 2018-12-14 15:24 to 2018-12-27 17:15)
- [Old books you would like to have reprinted with high-quality typesetting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/318839/70594) (MathOverflow)
  (12 days, 22 hours, from 2018-12-17 12:30 to 2018-12-30 11:27)
- [How do you deal with colleagues, acquaintances asking you for knowledge that you gained with months of effort?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/18650/321) (Interpersonal Skills)
  (11 days, 21 hours, from 2018-09-21 09:00 to 2018-10-03 06:50)
- [Police forcing me to install Jingwang spyware app, how to minimize impact?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/194353/71850) (Information Security)
  (11 days, 16 hours, from 2018-09-24 15:50 to 2018-10-06 08:30)
- [Top developer doing more home office than allowed](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/119816/33983) (The Workplace)
  (11 days, 13 hours, from 2018-09-27 00:20 to 2018-10-08 13:50)
- [All 0s (zeros) in a bank card's CVC code](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/200243/71850) (Information Security)
  (11 days, 12 hours, from 2018-12-22 22:48 to 2019-01-03 11:18)
- [Why is Gbt3fC79ZmMEFUFJ a weak password?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/201210/71850) (Information Security)
  (11 days, 12 hours, from 2019-01-10 20:06 to 2019-01-22 08:27)
- [What logical fallacy is “If you don't like it, move!”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/57335/14245) (Philosophy)
  (11 days, 12 hours, from 2018-11-22 04:09 to 2018-12-03 16:15)

It's rather interesting that the top 4 (and #8) questions were posted during Winter Bash 2018.

Comment: The JavaScript `(a == 1 && a == 2 && a == 3)` one must be the longest.

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true)? It was posted before the data collection started so we really can't know.

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ I'm not 100% sure, but it looks it wasn't on the HNQ list on January 29th, 14 days after posting. At least not on the [first 30](http://web.archive.org/web/20180129075255/https://stackexchange.com/) and the [last 50](http://web.archive.org/web/20180129150632/https://stackexchange.com/?page=2). The last trace I could find is on [Jan 25th](http://web.archive.org/web/20180125091935/https://stackexchange.com/). You might be confused by one of its [clones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48383521/4751173).

Comment: Also, the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48270127/timeline) shows a decline of upvotes after the 26th. It looks like it managed at most 11 days, not enough to make the list.