# Newsletter algorithm is biased

Tags: bug, newsletter

I stumbled upon this *bug* (it's not a bug, just a design flaw) by accident.

I posted a [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94262/why-is-mayo-in-the-alchemy-jug) that got over 30+ votes (not so common in the RPG community). A part of me was giddy by knowing I'd show up in the newsletter (I'm a child, I know). A week passed, I got my newsletter, but my question wasn't on it.

After digging a little bit, I understood that a newsletter came out on that same day (3rd of February), a few hours later. By then, my question wasn't *popular* yet. But because it was posted in that period, the following newsletter did not include it.

In other words, the newsletter doesn't really reflect popular questions in the last week, since questions asked 6 days ago have 6 more days of votes than questions asked on that same day. A simple (and *fair*) fix for this is to use a fixed 7-day period to measure popularity since the question was asked.

E.g, assuming the newsletter comes out on the 20th, questions considered are asked from the 6th (where votes are counted until the 13th) until the 13th (where votes are counted until the 20th). Each question would have a 7-day period to be deemed popular. Sure, the newsletter would have 2-week old questions, but at least all questions have a fair chance of showing up.

TL,DR

### Questions asked close to the newsletter deadline don't show up in the newsletter even if they are popular, since the newsletter counts votes across the last week, which doesn't give the same vote-window to all questions.

Comment: This is interesting because a lesser velocity (say votes / hour or even votes / day) would prevent quite a few questions from smaller sites ever making it in at all.

Comment: @TimPost This was something I observed years ago on SO with some of my answers that went viral. Some hit the newsletter, others didn't. And it was all about the luck of timing. In the end though, it was still a fish in the tank compared to the multicollider. (before it got replaced with the randomized list on the side)

Comment: @Mysticial FWIW you stopped getting rep from HNQ not because of randomizing but because they [practically disabled this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773 "as discussed in more details here") at Stack Overflow, "If you take time to monitor questions in the hot network list, you may notice that SO ones seem to leave it much faster compared to questions from smaller sites..."

Comment: @gnat That was the case even in the old multicollider. Back then it was already weighted to push SO questions off much more quickly than smaller sites. The randomization of the HNQ combined with the overall drop in SO question quality has meant that there hasn't been a "super-viral" question on SO in years. (Though [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619165/github-incorrectly-formatting-a-number-in-a-list-as-roman-numerals) seems to have broken that ice. But I can't tell if that was linked externally.)

Comment: good point @Mysticial - it is indeed possible that randomization merely made this tweak easier to see. As for that funny 666-question, I saw it. To me it's of the kind that is essentially unrelated to HNQ, questions that become popular organically (as opposed to being spammed via sidebar). Such questions stick in hot list _despite_ the system that tries to push them out. :) At SO I observe such questions about [once in 2-3 months](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=score%3a200%20is%3aquestion)