# How to Protect a Question?

Tags: support, protected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

How do you protect a question?

Is there a link I can click?  I have sufficient rep, but I don't see a `protect` link.  Are there any conditions that might prevent this link from appearing?

Comment: @Robert: My question was **HOW** to protect a question, **not** "what is a protected question" or "who can protect a question"... what part of that is a dup?

Comment: Look beside the "flag" button on questions.

Comment: @Jon: I see `close`...

Comment: Errrrrrrr... ironically, after I edit the FAQ, this *will* be a dupe of the FAQ. :)

Comment: @Jon: More like the other way around... I think we should close the FAQ as a dupe. >:D

Comment: Okay, [the FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question/52765#52765) is updated. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @Jon: Assuming it's correct, yes it does. Now let's close the FAQ as a dupe. :P