# Not being able to answer protected questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, protected-questions

I wanted to answer a question on Ask Ubuntu but it is marked as "protected". On a protected question, you can not answer if your reputation is less than 10 or is equal to 101 (associated bonus).

It is true that my rep there is only 37, but is it normal that I can not answer protected questions knowing that I already offered 150 of my reputation as a bounty to an answerer there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow people to answer protected questions if they have earned at least some amount of combined SE rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129223/282094)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> On a protected question, you can not answer if your reputation is less than 10 or is equal to 101 (associated bonus)

Not exactly. If you are eligible to the association bonus, you would need 110 reputation on the site (association bonus + 10 reputation earned on the site).

The does mean that if you gave away any bounties (even if otherwise you would be eligible to answer a protected question) that drop you to below 110 required, you will not be able to answer such a question.

Comment: But 10 rep earned on the site could be 5 approved suggested edits, bringing this OP's rep to 47 and eligible to answer protected questions, right?

Comment: @rene - nope. As it stands, the calculation is overly simple - if a user has gotten the assoc. bonus, we look for over 101 rep.

Comment: @rene The OP earned around 85-ish rep on that site; he just gave away 150 rep in a bounty (the association bonus plus 50 rep he earned on that site).

Comment: @Servy Well, actually, as it is designed, he gave away the complete 85 rep on the site first, and then another 65 of the association bonus, so that the rep on that site is spent first on a bounty. Which has in turn an implication for the protected question. (Sorry for ranting about this like this, but I really think this is bad. On the other hand, I also think you shouldn't spend association rep on a bounty (that's not what its meant for), but that's a completely different story.