# Protected questions and overall SO network reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers, privileges, protected-questions

I recently wanted to give an answer on an SO platform, but instead had to write a comment.

The weird thing is, that I think the comment would have been a decent answer, which in turn could bump me well above the threshold to answer protected questions.

I also have the 100 rep bonus, and 1900 reputation or more overall on the SO network.

I think it would be cool if a user with enough reputation say 1000 or 1500 overall on the SO network (real reputation not with the bonus counted), could still answer protected questions.

The reason is that I think it's unlikely that someone with a lot of reputation would write a bad answer on another SO platform.

I don't know if it can be implemented though and what each SO platform has access to.

I mean you can still give the information in a comment, or ask someone in chat to post it for you, but you will forfeit the potential gain of reputation, which then would allow you to answer future protected questions (which are the ones you are most likely to see, because you're likely not actively search on that particular network, but instead only see the hot networks)

Ofcourse you could argue that this is design, but somehow I think that this could prevent a few people which could post gem answers for specific situation/contexts they are familiar with, but are simply not active on that network.

Comment: See [Allow people to answer protected questions if they have earned at least some amount of combined SE rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129214/307988) for the reasoning on this (which is a dupe really, except for the rep amount you suggest)

Comment: Thanks for the link, the wording nullified my search results funnily enough. Thus I'm leaving this as a duplicate so other people search for "protected question overall reputation" will find my result and can find the other question.