# What exactly is threshold for answering protected questions?

Tags: support, privileges, protected-questions, association-bonus

This is said in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/350567)

> #### Privileges not tied to a specific threshold
>
> - To answer protected questions, you need to gain 10 reputation on the site – the association bonus does not count. In other words, the reputation threshold for answering protected questions if you have the bonus is **110**, not 10.

If my Maths and English aren't too bad, `gained 10 = 1 + 10 = 11` (or 111 with assoc-bonus). But it says **110**, as well as a lot of other places:

- Another FAQ: [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764)

  > #### Who can answer a protected question?
  >
  > Users with **10 or more reputation** can answer a protected question. However, the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check.
- [An answer from an ex-staff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116667)

  > In practice the check is all bodged up and inconsistent. In particular, if you associate an account and get no bonus (cause you have less than 200 rep) we arbitrarily decide that **you need 111 rep** to post answers.

Those conflicts are really embrangling. Question:

**Is it 10/110 or 11/111 (new user / user with assoc bonus)?**

Comment: I'm not sure, but isn't that site specific?

Comment: I think what actually matters is that a user gets at least 1 upvote and keeps a positive score on that particular site without counting the association bonus.

Comment: Its very hard to get *exactly* 110 rep as a new user to a site. I also distinctly remember the "10 reputation on the site" rule was a result of HNQ related dogpiling on questions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Have an answer to post?

Comment: I suppose I might!

Comment: Technically, the 1 rep out of 101 **is** site rep.

Comment: @rene Not dupe.

Comment: Related: [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions because I gave away earned rep in bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231875/241919) (the question is not a dupe, but the answer explains it)

Answer (score 1):

I think "you need to *gain* 10 reputation on the site" is the important bit. It's clear and unambiguous. 9 is too little, 11 is more than 10 (and a very odd number to get, as we see).

While it's practically impossible to *get* 110 or 10 reputation without a very specific set of changes in reputation (1 base + 1 upvote (+10) + 1 selected answer (+15) + 12 downvotes(-24)?), you'd essentially be gaining 9 *not* 10 reputation here.

I think Adam has an off by 1 error here.

Comment: (Isn’t 11 just 10 reputation point plus 1) which everyone starts with?

Comment: yup, but it was the subtle monty python reference,  or the badly bodged spinal tap reference

Comment: No, I think that "gain" means "attain"... every rep requirement is a round number (either ending in 0 or 5). I think 10 is correct.

Comment: It's actually much easier to get 110 rep here on meta: one answer upvote, then downvote one answer. On other sites it's more difficult since you don't have the privilege to downvote.

Comment: If it hasn't been fixed (which looks like it), then [you can really answer protected questions at exactly 110 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231498/stack-exchange-doesnt-allow-me-to-answer-protected-questions-because-i-gave-awa#comment763216_231875).