# Can we have an option to disable or minimise the HNQ box?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

HNQ regularly causes problems for smaller sites, and can potentially display NSFW topics on any site (as seen in today's challenge with IPS questions showing up on other sites)

As there are questions on IPS (and Parenting and other sites) that are appropriate on their own site but potentially trouble when they pop up in the SO sidebar at work my feature request is possibly less trouble than the [options discussed previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308004/154443) - can we offer the option for the HNQ list to open minimised, or possibly even be disabled on a per user basis? It would save me a lot of time and effort on small sites I moderate, protecting posts from the influx of people less familiar with site scope.

Comment: Can't help but quote [that workaround](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6859/98028) someone proposed on SFF meta... :D

Comment: Do you mean the option as an individual to disable it, or to switch it off for a whole site?

Comment: In this feature request I meant per user, but yes, that could also be a good idea - would require site community to agree.

Comment: There is also a user script available at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7807/36296 to remove the HNQ

Comment: @samcarter - that will help many of those who don't want nsfw stuff on their screen. I would still prefer a toggle switch for it with default set to off :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop I totally agree that it would be nice to be able to configure this in ones preferences.

Comment: @chrisf I think you are right. Sounds like what I want. Can't believe I didn't find it in my search. Well, I can... Blooming SE search :-)