# Does it make my question valuable?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

I post this question [structure-of-a-comment-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380295/structure-of-a-comment-system/10660165#10660165) on `Apr 30` in StackOverflow.After 20 days I got this message upon my question.

**protected by Robert Harvey♦ 3 hours ago
This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.**

My question is protected first time. What it means.Why it is protected? Does it make my question valuable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your question might be quite valuable, but it doesn't have much to do with the fact that it's been protected. Questions are protected (either automatically, or by a moderator or community member with 15k+ reputation) when they seem to be attracting a lot of spam or non-answers.

In this case, your question has received two spam answers from the same user within 5–10 minutes of each other, so it was a prime candidate for protection.

When a question is protected, that just means that someone has to have earned at least 10 reputation on the current site (the +100 account association bonus does not count) in order to be able to answer. The "barrier to entry" is raised slightly, with the hopes of deterring bad answers, while not completely preventing *any* answers (as would happen if the question were locked).

Also see: [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Answer (score 2):

Your question was a target for spammers, who knows why. The mod protected it to prevent further spam.