# Old question with a great, accepted answer gets a new, poor answer- etiquette?

Tags: discussion, answers, review

I recently gained review tools on SO, and I noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771154/451590) just got added to a year-old question with a great, upvoted and accepted answer. The answer that has been added *could* answer the question (I'm not sure), but it is obviously far inferior to the accepted one. What does one do about this? Is it still valid- or should I flag it *something*?

Comment: That answer is **clearly** an advertisement for his blog. "Andrew Rauh" `-->` "andrewrauh.com" - not too difficult to figure it out.

Comment: @animuson You're correct, that's a bad example. But the question still stands- let's say the answer isn't a blatant advertisement.

Comment: Ugh. Good-faith but bad answers is especially common with people who ask bad questions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Downvote the answer, and upvote the great, accepted answer. Why would any more be necessary? I don't see what is special about this compared to any other time a bad answer is posted.

If you feel really strongly, you can always leave a comment on the answer and ask the user to remove it. (Or, if you have [at least 20k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user), cast a vote of your own to delete it.)

If it's happening repeatedly on the same question (e.g., it appears to be a popular target for "spammy" answers), flag the question and ask for it to be [protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), or protect it yourself [if you have 15k rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions).