# "Look at all the questions I can't answer"

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, protected-questions

I'm a new user. I have a few measly reputation points on some sites. But I have none at security. I just saw a "hot" question and I'd like to contribute.

[VP of IT claims he unhashed 100% of all 16k employees' PWs. Is he lying to us?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24637/vp-of-it-claims-he-unhashed-100-of-all-16k-employees-pws-is-he-lying-to-us)

But I just freaking can't. I have no points to answer. Because I need 10 points. The explanation is:

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site.

Really? Why only on this site? If I have 200+ points (combined) on the other sites that must mean I probably won't just answer with "me too" or "thanks". I probably know my way around.

I see the "Hot questions" and say to myself: "Look at all those questions I can't answer". If you don't trust me, don't bother me presenting questions that I can contribute. If I want to answer that, I'll have to mine reputation points on that site.

How does that help?

On a related note, I never understood why I must 50 points to comment. Comment are way more discrete and limited than answer. But it needs more reputation to comment that to answer.

And I actually wanted to comment on the question. The comment would point to (what I consider) a very interesting article on Ars about password security: http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/08/passwords-under-assault/

I can't even send the user who asked the question the link.

I understand you might not trust me, but just let me try it. The moment you realize I'm BSing you, you can tell me to STFU.

Why do not allow new users to answer a hot question / comment and have it automatically deleted if one measly "trusted" user downvote it?

**Edit**

The feature request is: let new users (who are already have points) on other sites, answer hot questions and comment. But as soon as one trusted user downvotes that answer/comment, make it disappear. Let the community moderate it.

Or just don't bother showing it to me.

Comment: Related: [What is a protected question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)

Comment: If you are such a good answerer, earning the 10 or 50 points necessary will be no problem at all.

Comment: And if you have 200+ points on another site, shouldn't the [association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) kick in anyway, resolving all your problems? You don't have that yet, but that issue is already solved.

Comment: @Bart - No, these 100 bonus points don't count when it comes to protected questions (but it does enable commenting). Tried that on [Programmers.SE] once. This is detailed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/7586 - "the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check". I have 47K on Stack Overflow, what couldn't answer a protected question in Programmers.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, every community has a right to decide who are their trusted users. A trusted user on [User Experience site](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) may or may not be able to provide good answers on [IT Security site](http://security.stackexchange.com/). So a user has to earn his/her privilege to become a trusted user of every Stack Exchange site individually.

Comment: @Kobi D'oh and of course the very message states "earned at least 10 reputation **on this site**". Thanks for that heads-up. Though of course 10 points are trivially easy to obtain on any site.

Comment: I have 200 points combined. Not on a single one. I'm knew to the StackExchange network. Glad to know that when I have 200+ on a single site I can comment everywhere. But I DID NOT claimed to be a good answerer. And If I was, I'd have to hunt some other little question and answer just so I can answer a protected question? I disagree.

Comment: Protected questions are protected for a reason. Prove on the site that you can be a reasonably good user there (10 rep, nothing more. Even if you don't answer, that's only 5 edits) and you can answer them to your heart's content. I really don't see the problem in that.

Comment: I would hardly quantify providing _one_ good answer that gets _one_ up vote as _mining_ for reputation.

Answer (score 15):

> Really? Why only on this site? If I have 200+ points on the other sites that must mean I probably won't just answer with "me too" or "thanks". I probably know my way around.

In general? Yes. On the site you've never visited before today because you found it via the Hot Questions list (or via Reddit, Hacker News etc.)? Maybe not. Different sites have different scopes and different standards. People coming to the site from Hot Questions very often don't get familiar with the community itself before actually posting; that's a problem and it often results in lots of extra work for moderators and users with moderator tools (flagging, deleting, editing).

Questions are usually protected because other people have already given non-answers that had to be deleted. Questions in the Hot Questions list are often well answered by the time they're in that list to boot; it's hard to get "hot" without lots of answer upvotes as well as views/question upvotes.

You *can* comment on protected questions...but you need 50 rep, or you need the site association bonus. So the only reason you couldn't is because you haven't earned the priviledge.

> Why do not allow new users to answer a hot question / comment and have it automatically deleted if one measly "trusted" user downvote it?

Hot questions are pretty much the worst ones for us to allow that to happen on; they've often *already* got a relatively large amount of answers and even more comments. It's often bad enough to deal with all the comments from users who should *know* how SE works yet still leave "+1 great answer" etc fluff comments on posts.

In addition, having a separate set of "you can post... *maybe*" rules for protected questions just complicates the whole thing. Keep it simple.