# How can I share a helpful solution with the Community as my first post?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users, protected-questions

I just discovered a significant updated solution for the following topic:

[Add alternating row color to SQL Server Reporting services report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376/add-alternating-row-color-to-sql-server-reporting-services-report)

I feel so compelled to share it, but this would be my first post.

How can I go about commenting to the topic or starting my own topic.

The issue has been alternate row coloring in a tablix.  An exhausted topic, but I had the issue of alternate row shading where the row group was sorted Z-A.  Using the Code.AlternateColor from the comments, I was able to achieve alternate row coloring on a sorted table and since I spent a lot of time trying to find the solution and realizing so many others have the same issue, I want to share.

Let me know the best way to share my solution (without a question really).

Comment: Any time you feel that a contribution would benefit and be helpful to the community - post it. Be it your 1st or 42nd post (and beyond). In this case, it shouldn't be too hard to get the 10 required rep to post an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of the 0.1% of questions that have been [protected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764) due to the number of non-answers they were getting from first-time users. To answer it, you'll need to gain a little bit of reputation on the site first. One upvote on one answer will do it, so watch the front page, find one question you can answer, answer it, and hopefully you'll get that one necessary upvote and you'll be able to answer that reporting services question as your second contribution.