# Protected Question has new answer from 1-rep user

Tags: support, protected-questions

I have this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/19810443#19810443) in my favourites so I see when people add to it.

The question attracts many users who add another answer which just repeats what has said before so it has been Protected

However Protected says

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam
>   answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10
>   reputation on this site.

So how did this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19810443/151019) by a user with a reputation of 1 get added?

Comment: I'm noting voting irregularities, I bet they were >10 recently

Comment: The user lost 110 rep because a user that voted on his posts was removed, and he has been suspended for voting irregularities. He *had* more than 10 rep before that point, and may still have enough today, if it wasn't for the suspension.

Comment: OK - perhaps we need to rise the bar on protected questions to several hundred or even more - I'll raise a separate question if I can't find a duplicate

Comment: Not really. One crappy user doesn't make for a systemic problem.

Comment: I'll +1 that request to raise the bar a bit.

Comment: There is no point in doing so. It's there to prevent spam. Not to exclude a significant portion of our users.

Comment: To determine if raising the bar is desired, an analysis should probably be done first to determine how many answers by users with rep between 10 and (whatever we want the new limit to be) were upvoted versus downvoted. If it's found to not be viable, perhaps we can extend this analysis to include votes on the question, number of answers, votes on the answers, views, whatever else.

Comment: OK seeing this [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) looks like Protection is for Spam and I am wanting something between Protected and lock

Comment: @Dukeling The given question would not have all the crappy answers caught by that query there are repeat answers that have a positive vote

Comment: Oh wait, that should probably be **deleted or** downvoted versus **non-deleted** upvoted answers. @Mark I don't really understand you last comment (or maybe I'm not sure why it's directed at me), does this help - I'm talking about on a larger scale - we should check **all** answers to **all** protected questions by users with said reputation - if the ratio of deleted or downvoted questions is high enough, there's merit in the request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That user had >10 when they posted the answer. They currently have 1 reputation due to suspension. See their [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629467/dan-both?tab=reputation)