# Add spacing / padding to "Protected By..." and "Not the answer you're looking for

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When viewing a protected question while logged out, there appears to be some padding missing. If you look closely it seems that "Not the answer you're looking for?..." overlaps the "Protected..." message. This looks to be present in all site designs, although potentially not in the beta sites layout? ([example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17005/produce-the-number-2014-without-any-numbers-in-your-source-code/17103#17103))

[image]

**Live Examples:**

[How can I tag friends in a YouTube video on Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15674/how-can-i-tag-friends-in-a-youtube-video-on-facebook)

[Does using == in JavaScript ever make sense?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/268124/does-using-in-javascript-ever-make-sense)

[What happens when you don't wind up the music box in Five Nights at Freddy's 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191831/what-happens-when-you-dont-wind-up-the-music-box-in-five-nights-at-freddys-2)

[How can I reset the answers of the security questions of my Apple ID?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60656/how-can-i-reset-the-answers-of-the-security-questions-of-my-apple-id)

Present in latest Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: Could you add a link to that question and your browser version ! ?

Comment: Sorry it was the webmaster's site (beta, stackexchange).  Browser is chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m

Comment: Hi Jon - I just came across this bug, and found your meta question when about to post my own. Added some extra details that I was going to put in my post, hope you don't mind!

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed at some point, probably as a side effect of other styling changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overlap is caused by the CSS rule `margin-bottom: -5px` applied to the `.question-status` class.  Simply deactivating the rule eliminates it, although it still doesn't leave any actual margin between the status box and the notice below it.

Changing the status box styling is somewhat complicated by the fact that, apparently, it can appear in many locations.  For example, here on MSO, it's [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) placed just below the question, but *above* the answers, while on [web apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/did-facebook-ever-had-a-dislike-button) the placement is like in your screenshot.

One simple fix that should cause any unwanted side effects would be to add the following CSS rule:

```css
.question-status + .bottom-notice { margin-top: 15px }
```

This will add an extra 15px margin to the "Not the answer you're looking for?" notice whenever it appears below the question status box, canceling the negative margin on the box and adding 10 pixels of actual margin for legibility.

**Edit:** While waiting for a proper fix from the SE devs, I've added the fix above to [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) 1.8.