# How to bootstrap reputation as a new user?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I recently referred someone else to the StackExchange network. However, I was  quickly pointed to a pretty embarrassing problem:

The new account started with one reputation. But with just one reputation, one is unable to upvote, unable to comment, unable to answer a question, and not even able to put this question on meta.

Someone please advise: how do you start participating in Stack Exchange if you don't have a question? Do you really have to make something up?

Comment: You don't need rep to answer a question.

Comment: @Mysticial You do if most interesting questions are protected.

Comment: @tepples Not really a problem. It's generally discouraged to pile answers on old "interesting" questions that already well-answered. Often times, that's precisely why they are protected.

Comment: @Mysticial I have seen protected questions with zero or one answer.

Comment: @tepples That can happen if the question attracts a lot of spam or low-quality answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The new account started with one reputation. But with just one reputation, one is unable to upvote...

True. Get 15 rep, so you'll be able to upvote.

> ...unable to comment...

Yeah. 50 rep and you'll get this privilege.

> ...unable to answer a question...

Beep. You can answer any question, except of [protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) questions (answering protected questions requires 10 rep), maybe you did accidentally choose protected question?

> ...not even able to put this question on meta.

Posting on per-site meta requires 5 rep on its main site, so, yes, its true.

As a new user, I *suggest* you to start answering questions. Every upvote on your answer will give you +10 rep (while question upvote gives only +5 rep), so its the most efficient way to earn reputation :)

Comment: Don't forget that every accepted suggested edit will net you +2 reputation points (up to a limit) and there is no shortage of posts that could use some copyediting.

Comment: @Fish Agree. But the most efficient way is still answering ;).

Comment: *Posting on per-site meta requires 5 rep on main meta* you mean on the meta's main site?

Comment: @Won't yep, true. A small typo ;)