# Answer protected questions privilege earned, or not?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, help-center, protected-questions

Like you can see here : [Protected Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question#answer-52765)

> The +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check.

But when we are on our privilege, we earn this privilege even if we have only 101 points like you can see on the picture.

[image]

I think that if we put the privilege "answer protected question" with less opacity like the other :

[image]

It's more visible and understandable. What do you think?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!! This is f***n ridiculous. "Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site. " - well bugger me, I have over 100 - so why don't you just try to confuse me. May as well be "Potato, Potato, Potato, Potato. Maybe you can see this or not. We don't really care to elaborate."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think they should split the privileges in two, where you can show a hover or some extra text to indicate you need to have the required reputation on that site before you gain that privilege.

Maybe:

```
 10         | remove new user restrictions | Post more links

 10 on-site | answer protected questions   | You must have earned 10 or more reputation
                                             on this site to answer a protected questions
```

Comment: Yes, something like that will be good :)