# Remove user restrictions privilege "earned" at 101 rep with association bonus only?

Tags: bug, privileges, protected-questions, association-bonus

I know that as a new user(or one with only the association bonus like me), one cannot post answers to protected questions, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top):
[image] However, I noticed something very strange. When I click on the link that leads me to the "Remove New User Restrictions" page, on the side, it shows that I have earned the privilege on this site, which I have clearly not, being at 101 rep with the association bonus:
[image]
Question: is this a bug that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Feature Request asking for this to be fixed back in 2015: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256721/answer-protected-questions-privilege-earned-or-not

Comment: @Catija Do you know why this wasn't fixed?

Comment: Low priority? My guess is that fixing it in a useful way would be somewhat difficult and few people look at the privileges page, so the "harm" it does is limited. I think there's a more recent post about it somewhere but I can't find it at the moment. ... Found it :D

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the clarification! I still want to know when they'll fix it :)

Comment: I don't think the problem is on the privilege because you are indeed able to post more links with the association bonus compared to <10 rep users. The problem is with the rep requirement for protected question that it needs to be explicitly stated "the association bonus does not count" on the notice banner :(

Comment: Please see [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398).