# 10 reputation requirement to answer a question, but I have 101

Tags: support, reputation

I frequently browse popular stack questions that appear on the right side of any site. Every now and then I find myself capable and willing to voice opinion/answer a question. This is why I pushed my rep on Stack Overflow, and rocketed (completely legitimate) from 150 to 300-something, in few hours, to get the 100 bonus on all stack sites. (The one you get once you hit 200 rep on any stack site)

So here I am having (similarly to my meta profile) 101 rep and trying to answer 
[How to prove the authenticity of a screenshot?](https://superuser.com/questions/1010186/how-to-prove-the-authenticity-of-a-screenshot)

And yet I get

> Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

What gives? Isn't the core idea behind the "100 rep on all sites" award exactly to allow me to post answers? If it says I have 101 (https://superuser.com/users/299232/%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2), and yet it would only recognize the original 1 and disregard the awarded 100. What is the point of even getting 100 if I can't take advantage of the perks they should give me...

Comment: The bonus is awarded because you have proven that you know your way around the basic features of any Stack Exchange website, and with those 100 extra points you can now comment, vote, flag and create bounties on all SE sites. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/.

However, you can't use this bonus to answer protected questions.

Comment: You might find this feature request interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270842/245360.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Indeed i might, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It states:

> 10 reputation on this site

That actually means:

> 10 reputation **gained** on this site

You have to receive 10 reputation through upvotes or edits. *Then* you will be able to answer protected questions. The network association bonus doesn't count. To read how this works, see the FAQ: [What is a “protected” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/245360), specifically *Who can answer a protected question?*