# What should we do if we think a question should be protected?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

If I feel a question of particular value as a "relatively frequently asked question" should be protected, what course of action should be taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why* do you want to protect the question? The only thing that the protection does, is preventing new answers from new users. If it attracts multiple noisy answers from new users, it will be [automatically protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/295232).

If you're still convinced that the question must be protected, you can try to [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) a >15k-user or a moderator who has answered the question (or placed a comment) - that person, if he/she agrees with you, can protect the question manually.

I'd expect that if you flag the question for moderator attention, the flag will be declined.

Comment: I've written dozens of custom flags asking for protection, and almost all have been accepted. From my experience it's not something to recommend against.