# Misleading hover text for 'protect' option

Tags: bug, tooltips, wording, protected-questions

The hover text for the 'protect' option is slightly misleading:

> disallow answers by anonymous and very new low rep users

[image]

The word 'new' is off. It doesn't matter if the user is new or not; [only reputation matters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/295232).

I suggest to remove the word 'new', but there might be better options. As @Catija mentions in the comments, the word 'anonymous' might be incorrect, too.

Comment: Is "anonymous" even correct? If someone has an unregistered account with 10+ rep... are they prohibited from answering protected questions? If changed, it should be reflected in the help center here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions as well... since it uses the same wording.

Comment: @Catija depends whether you read the "low rep" description as only applying to very new or to both anonymous and very new.

Comment: @RobertLongson If anonymous is irrelevant and only rep matters, then including "anonymous" is ... unnecessary. If **all** anonymous users are prohibited regardless of reputation, then it is accurate.

Comment: only rep earned on the site matters (association bonus doesn't count), anonymous can answer if they have 10 rep.

Comment: That's what I have always thought... so, in that case, the only note that's necessary is "disallow answers by users with less than 10 locally-earned reputation points".

Comment: @Catija Anonymous just means "not logged in". Unregistered users aren't anonymous. Having said that, it *is* just a rep check against the threshold and whether or not someone's logged in is irrelevant.

Comment: @AdamLear but anonymous users can't answer anything... ? Or am I missing something.

Comment: @Catija The phrasing is slightly awkward, I agree. *But* anonymous users see the "question is protected" banner instead of the answer box, so I guess if you squint a little, it sort of makes sense? I'm not so much arguing for status quo on the tooltip as clarifying that unregistered != anonymous and the rep check is all that matters. In other words, an unregistered user with 10+ rep *can* answer. :)

Comment: Ah! I see. :) Thanks for the clarification @AdamLear It's good to know how the terminology is different than one might expect.

Comment: I suggest making it positive instead of negative: "allow answers only from users who have gained at least 10 reputation on the site"