# Non-anonymous "Thanks" or "Like" button

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, thanks

Today, upvoting is anonymous; the recipient knows they were upvoted, but they don't know who upvoted them, so it's not a public personal gesture. The only way to let someone know who likes your answer is to comment, often by saying "Thanks!" which adds nothing to the discussion.

**There should be some non-anonymous thing I can do to communicate that I (personally) appreciate your response.**

For example, Quora has an explicit “Thanks” button. Here's an example: http://www.quora.com/How-does-Twitter-make-money  As you can see, it has both upvoting *and* a "Thanks" button.  It works great; check it out.

I think we’ll see a lot more people posting great answers when they get positive feedback from a personal “Thank You.” It feels really good to receive personal thanks, especially from an expert who you respect.

Apropos https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/ and [Thanking users who answered my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/stack-overflow-etiquette-for-thanking-users-who-answered-my-question)

Jeff says that the way to thank users is to upvote and "pay it forward" by answering other questions.  I think that this argument goes against human nature, because the recipient doesn't know who did it (or even what they did). The point of saying "thank you" is to make a personal (ideally public) gesture of gratitude, which feels good to the recipient.

Comment: A dedicated button seems unnecessary; I'd rather the upvote button just not change a post's score if the user has insufficient rep (I just read the duplicate and realized that's what that feature-request is)

Comment: This question was marked as as a duplicate of [Use upvote button for "Thank You" if you don't have enough rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72364/use-upvote-button-for-thank-you-if-you-dont-have-enough-rep) but they're completely different solutions to a similar problem. This post suggests adding a non-anonymous gratitude gesture (upvoting is anonymous); that post suggests allowing people to pseudo-upvote when your reputation is low.

Comment: @Dan Why would it need to be non-anonymous? It kind of goes against how the site works to have an anonymous upvote and a non-anonymous upvote system at the same time

Comment: Quora has both "Thanks" and upvoting.  It works great; check it out.

Comment: Getting thanked by an expert you respect is better (feels better) than getting thanked by a random user with 15 reputation.

Comment: Personally, I feel pretty good when an expert, like Jon Skeet, takes time to correct, comment, or point out a feature I missed. I am still learning a lot and constructive commentary from anyone, including those who downvote my answers, gives me more confidence in what I know and teaches me what I don't know.

Comment: This is a valid suggestion and it has generated some good, thoughtful discussion. Why are there so many downvotes? I agree that this is probably a bad idea, and the world might end if it were implemented, but still, downvoting thoughtful discussions seems like a bad idea as well.

Comment: we do how have an anonymous "this was useful / this was not useful" feature, however: [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)

Answer (score 46):

I agree that this isn't a duplicate because of the focus on "show non-anonymous thanks", but I don't think the proposal has merit.

Seeing a random assortment of 10-20 users who clicked a prefabricated, mindless *I liked this* button **does not make the internet better**.

Or, if you prefer, in image form:

[image]

If you really want to thank someone, either

1. Write a useful explanatory comment on their post that goes deeper than mere "thanks!". Not difficult to do, and a hell of a lot more heartfelt than "I clicked a button to show you that I care".
2. Or, best of all, [pay it forward and thank them by extending the same courtesy to others that they extended to you](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/) -- that is, **answer other people's questions!**

Comment: Oak liked this answer.

Comment: Greg Hewgill liked this answer, but wants his 30 seconds back.

Comment: It doesn't have to be that silly.  Only show high rep thanks, for example.  Quora only shows Thanks from people I'm following; other Thanks are just sent privately via email.  Honestly, whatever other problems Quora has, their Thanks button works pretty well.

Comment: @dan that has about zero percent in common with our model; we care intensely about the information you can share with us, but not at all about *who you are*

Comment: +1 for I don't care ;-).

Comment: Hello71 liked this

Comment: My friend likes this answer, but wishes to remain anonymous. The user in question has upvoted the answer.

Comment: I think this is the first time I upvotes Jeff on meta. Wow, I think that says that I appreciate the answer. So, "Thanks, Jeff. Your image is missing a freehand circle, though..."

Comment: muntoo *loved* this.

Comment: @Moshe [Done](http://i.imgur.com/0yqP7.png)

Comment: WHY NOT??
Adding something like this could very well allow people to know who their friends and enemies are.  Then, [alliances could be formed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2o15QPr_SNs), then we could have more petty disputes about downvotes and why and why didn't you like this and page after page of name-mentioning upvote GLORY!!

Answer (score 12):

I want to comment on one specific aspect of this:

> The point of saying "thank you" is to make a personal (ideally public) gesture of gratitude, which feels good to the recipient.

(and from a comment):

> Getting thanked by an expert you respect is better (feels better) than getting thanked by a random user with 15 reputation

There are a handful of people in the tags where I'm active who I respect greatly, because their answers are informative, well-researched and well-written. The experts.

They've taught me a great deal, by correcting, disputing, or clarifying my answers, or more often just by posting *better* answers (which I read, am humbled, and delete my own inferior answer). But I can't recall a single instance where I've been *thanked* by one of them. I count as high praise the very rare instances where we both answer and the expert deletes *his* answer.

It's the non-experts who post "thank you!" comments, and thus I rather suspect it would be the non-experts who would use a "Thanks button". They're the most grateful, as they are the ones with the most to learn and the least to contribute.

You've designed a feature for streamlining ego-stroking praise, but those most likely to use it would be those whose praise means - by your own admission - the least.

Comment: I agree, a thanks is a thanks, regardless of the reputation of the thanker. The reputation system is a good for checks and balances for maintaining the site, nothing more...

Answer (score -2):

Well, I agree with the 'Wood that this information is noisy and irrelevant to most users of the site.

## However.

Its not completely useless information to a poster.

Its all about the unobtrusive UI's.  When I click upvote, a white box appears.  Eventually it becomes like the answering machine - "You know what to do."

[image]

On voting, you can either fill it in, or just leave it (which is equivalent to hanging up without leaving a message).

Anonymous voting is a site wide setting that can be switched on/off on the profile page.

```
Cowardice mode?    On / Off
```

The useful info to the poster is displayed on flyover of the up/downvote widgets.

[image]

Comment: All this does is leave people open to retaliation.

Comment: Welcome all System Gamers, trolls and gang-members!

Comment: @Al Everett Hence __cowardice mode__.  This system does hope/assume people grow up past that, however.

Comment: So, if I think your answer is bunk, and I don't feel like leaving myself open to retaliation, that makes me a coward?

Comment: ______YES______.

Comment: By the cowards ` `