# How are the categories assigned in new Area 51 layout?

Tags: discussion, area-51

[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) has a new layout with categories on the left. My question is - how are proposals assigned to those categories and by whom?

I ask because I'm thinking of my main proposal: [Wikipedia and Wikis](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikipedia-and-wikis). It is currently under [Technology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology) which makes sense. But what about the other categories? E.g. given that it includes [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), why isn't it also listed under [Culture](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture)? Or since it includes moderating for businesses, why isn't it included under [Business](http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/2/business) as well? *(Yes, I know someone will say that with this proposal I could argue that it could go under almost any category - that's the point - how are these assigned?)*

And related - are these categories fixed for all time? If not, how can they be changed?

Comment: And where is the line drawn between Culture and Recreation? Guitars? (Er, never mind, Guitars is in Arts. And not Life, either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Michael Mrozek's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76776/how-are-the-categories-assigned-in-new-area-51-layout/76777#76777) is correct for your main question.  To answer the other questions:

- All proposals will only be in one category.  Sometimes the line is a little blurry, but we want to force proposals to pick a category because it will help define the scope of the site
- Moderators can change the category of a proposal.  If you think a category should be changed, create a discussion, e.g. "Should Wikipedia and Wikis be in the Culture category?"

If proposals need to change category often, we may allow higher-rep users to vote to change category (like voting to close, delete, etc).

Comment: Robert, Rebecca & team. I know we're not meant to say thanks (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72307/thanks-a-lot-for-this-post-and-other-first-time-user-curiosities) but too bad - **thanks** for this new feature of creating discussions per proposal. It works really well. Excellent!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to choose a category when you make a new proposal; there's a [Propose a new Technology site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology) link at the bottom of the Technology category, but no equivalent link on the main page. I assume [Robert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) and [Rebecca](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rebecca-chernoff) manually sorted the existing proposals, since they didn't have categories chosen by the proposer

Comment: this is correct