# Does community user auto-protect old questions?

Tags: support, protected-questions

An [old question on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/34619/4377) with lots of views was just bumped by a spam user. The post was spam-flagged and removed, and the question was [simultaneously protected](https://superuser.com/posts/34619/revisions).

Does this mean this [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79812/should-we-automatically-protect-questions-that-are-at-least-a-certain-age) is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)? Is there any other criteria for auto-protecting or does this happen when an answer on an old, popular (metrics?) question gets spam-flag-removed?

For what it's worth, I thought I saw a similar behaviour yesterday, but I was not sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers) is the one that triggered that behavior. It's marked `status-complete`.

Comment: thanks @CodyGray I seem to have missed that question.

Comment: [YEAH!  THAT'S ME, BABY!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers/1228)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Cody said, this is [completed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers)

> This will be in the next build. **When the third answer on a question from a new (<10 rep) user is deleted, protection will be triggered automatically from Community**. There is one tweak though: each user only counts once when we're checking deleted (to eliminate the self-answers that should be comments on their own question case).